# AngularJS : test if variable exist coming from api side

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, haml

I have json metadata object coming from api side contain some property of an image and I want to test if a property exist or not, I'm working with angularJS and coffeescript and haml for the views.

here is the js code that fetch data :

```
getImages = ->
    listImage = []

    for sheet in $scope.report.report_sheets()
      for composed in sheet.report_fragments()
        for fragment in composed.report_fragments()
          if fragment.fragment_type is 'images'
            for media in fragment.media()
              if media.metadata.date_time_original
                media.metadata.date_time_original = moment.utc(media.metadata.date_time_original).local().format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A')
              listImage.push media
    listImage
```

and here is haml side :

```
.directive-report-images{ ng_show: 'conditionIsChecked && fragment._parentConditionChecked' }
  .row
    .col-md-4
      .title
        %h5.black {{ fragment.title }}
    .col-md-8
      %report_fragment_visibility
      .row{ ng_if: 'fragment.media().length <= 2' }
        .col-md-6.thumbnail{ ng_repeat: "img in fragment.media() | notArchived | orderBy:'order'" }
          %img.pointer{ ng_src: "{{ img.contentUrl() }}", ng_click:'openCarouselModal(img)' }
          %p {{ img.comment }}
          .photo-date{ng_if: "img.metadata.date_time_original" }
            %p {{ img.metadata.date_time_original}}

  .row{ ng_if: 'fragment.media().length > 2' }
    .col-md-12
      .row
        .col-md-4.thumbnail{ ng_repeat: "img in fragment.media() | notArchived | orderBy:'order'" }
          %img.pointer{ ng_src: "{{ img.contentUrl() }}", ng_click:'openCarouselModal(img)' }
          %p {{ img.comment }}
          %p.photo-date {{ img.metadata.date_time_original }}
```

I want to test for the **media.metadata.date_time_original** to show it if exist and not if null !

I got this error in my console :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'date_time_original' of null

Comment: Are you getting `metadata`? `metadata` seems undefined

Comment: yes I'm getting metadata from rails api and it's working when I have image that have the property date_time_original, but when the server send a photo that doesn't have this property automatically that will be null in angularJS side , that's why I want to test it before showing that variable in html side !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a check using it i.e check if `media.metadata` exists and then proceed further.

Your current code:

```
getImages = ->
    listImage = []

    for sheet in $scope.report.report_sheets()
      for composed in sheet.report_fragments()
        for fragment in composed.report_fragments()
          if fragment.fragment_type is 'images'
            for media in fragment.media() 
                media.metadata.date_time_original = moment.utc(media.metadata.date_time_original).local().format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A')
              listImage.push media
    listImage
```

Change to:

```
getImages = ->
    listImage = []

    for sheet in $scope.report.report_sheets()
      for composed in sheet.report_fragments()
        for fragment in composed.report_fragments()
          if fragment.fragment_type is 'images'
            for media in fragment.media() 
                if (media.metadata) { // check here
                  media.metadata.date_time_original = moment.utc(media.metadata.date_time_original).local().format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A')
                  listImage.push media
                 }
    listImage
```